# How to redirect Webp files?

Tags: url-rewriting, uploads, redirect, regex

I was using all images as webp files for performance, however I've stopped using and deleted them (only .webp files) all from FTP. Now having problems with 404 errors. I would like to redirect all .webp files to jpg, png, gif, etc.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.jpg.webp
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.jpeg.webp
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.gif.webp
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.png.webp
```

TO...

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.jpg
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.jpeg
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.gif
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/file.png
```

Redirection plugin:

```
Source URL: ^(?!.*-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}).*\.(?:jpg.webp)

Target URL: https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/$1/$2/$3.$4
```

And it didn't work. Also, I tried it with htaccess but again, it didn't work. Is there a way to arrange that?

Comment: Browsers will try to reach the files directly, bypassing WP. You'll need to solve this on the server (.htaccess) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading it right, your regex has only two items in `()`, which means that only `$1` and `$2` have any meaning.

I copied your sample text and went to https://regex101.com/ (note: this is *not* an endorsement) to try to assemble a regex that'll cover all your images. Here's what I ended up with:

```
Pattern: ^(.*\/[0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/)([^\.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\.webp
Replacement: $1$2.$3
```

This is using the PCRE standard, which is apparently used in PHP < 7.3. You may need to tweak the regex if you're using PHP 7.3 or 7.4 (or higher), or if you want to use it in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: And works like a charm. Thank you!